# Windows 7: Redirect folder from PowerShell?

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell

Is there a way to redirect a folder using PowerShell on Windows 7? Bonus points for being able to do so as an admin to another account.

To be very clear, what I want to do is [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/redirect-folder-new-location#1TC=windows-7). I do NOT want to change the PS working directory, move a folder somewhere or create a shortcut/junction/symlink/hardlink (ie. all the things I could find solutions to on SU/SE). Just to preemt misunderstandings; I know this is a pretty obscure feature. :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This setting is controlled by the [Shell Folders / User Shell Folders](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962613.aspx) keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

> The entries in this subkey can appear in both the Shell Folders subkey
>   and the User Shell Folders and in both HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER. The entries that appear in user User Shell Folders
>   take precedence over those in Shell Folders. The entries that appear
>   in HKEY_CURRENT_USER take precedence over those in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

To modify those keys for another account you'd have to [load target user's registry hive](https://jrich523.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/powershell-loading-and-unloading-registry-hives/):

> PowerShell will by default expose your HKLM and HKCU hives via drives
>   which work because of the Registry PSProvider.

```powershell
get-psdrive

get-psprovider
```

> Since we see that it’s the provider that allows us to map these hives
>   we can take it a step further and map a hive from a file (update user
>   hives on a remote system). The problem with this is that the Registry
>   PSProvider doesn’t extend to files. However this doesn’t stop us.

```powershell
reg load 'HKLM\TempUser' $ntuserlocation

cd hklm:\TempUser

gci

New-PSDrive -Name HKMyUser -PSProvider Registry -Root HKLM\TempUser

cd HKMyUser:\

gci

cd c:

Remove-PSDrive HKMyUser

reg unload hklm\TempUser
```

> This all works great until we attempt to unload that hive file or in
>   some cases the unload works ok but we still have handles to the hive
>   file (you can use sysinternals Handle.exe to see this)
>
> Why is that if we removed the drive and asked Reg.exe to unload the
>   hive? The problem is that the system has not released the memory which
>   still has pointers into that file, preventing us from unloading the
>   hive or stopping us from doing other things.
>
> So what's the trick you ask?
>
> Ask the system to clean up those references that are no longer in use.

```powershell
[gc]::collect()
```

> This uses the static method Collect from the GC class in .NET which is
>   used for forcing the garbage collector to run and removing those
>   unused references.

#### References:

- [User Shell Folders](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962613.aspx)
- [Windows 7: Registry: differences between Shell Folders and User Shell Folders?](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/244817-registry-differences-between-shell-folders-user-shell-folders.html)
- [The long and sad story of the Shell Folders key](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031103-00/?p=41973/)
- [How to relink user folders in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/255965/how-to-relink-user-folders-in-windows-7)
- [How to redirect user shell folders to a specified path by using Profile Maker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/931087)
- [Powershell Script to Change Windows 7 User Profile Folders to UNC locations](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9992e37e-629a-4f38-9c9a-b4c1ede39191/powershell-script-to-change-windows-7-user-profile-folders-to-unc-locations)
- [PowerShell: Loading and Unloading Registry Hives](https://jrich523.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/powershell-loading-and-unloading-registry-hives/)